# Why does the pronoun and verb order vary in Polish language?

Tags: grammar, orthography, verbs, pronouns, polish

`My go nie lubimy` - we do not like him

`On nie kocha mnie` - he does not love me

Why in the first example `go` is followed by `nie lubimy`, but in the second sentence we have the opposite: `nie kocha` followed by `mnie`?

Comment: Because _go_ is the weak form, and those behave like clitics and tend to appear early in the sentence, while _mnie_ is a strong form. If you use the strong form _jego_ instead of the weak form _go_, you can see the difference.

Comment: My nie lubimy jego?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet what about `ten kot jej nie lubi`?

Comment: Not all the pronouns have separate strong and weak forms; some have only one that does ‘double duty’ as both, like _jej_. I don’t actually speak Polish, but I expect _ten kot nie lubi jej_ would also be fine.

Comment: honestly the more common form of the second sentence would be "on mnie nie kocha" - but word order in Polish can vary depending on a lot of factors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Polish pronouns *ja* (“I”), *ty* (“you singular, thou”), *on* (“he”), *ono* (“it”) have two sets of forms in the Genitive, Dative, and Accusative cases: a full form and a clitic form. The clitic form has no stress of its own and intonationally it is attached to the previous word, therefore *the clitic forms cannot begin a sentence* while the full forms can. The difference in usage is that the clitic forms are used by default, the full forms are used when the pronoun is specially underlined, when it is logically stressed and can be the first word in the sentence, when it's used in contrasting things. Your example `On nie kocha mnie` means ‘He doesn't love *me* (but loves someone else)’, while `On mię nie kocha` is neutral “He doesn't love me.”

*Ona* (“she”) and all the plural pronouns *my* (“we”), *wy* (“you”), *one* (“they feminine, neutral, and masculine inanimate”), *oni* (“they masculine animate”) do not have distinct clitic forms.
In the chart below, first the clitic forms are given, followed by the full forms.
Gen. of *ja* and Acc. of *ono* have no distinct clitic form.

```
Nom.    ja           ty             on          ono
Gen.    mnie         cię, ciebie    go, jego    go, jego
Dat.    mi, mnie     ci, tobie      mu, jemu    mu, jemu
Acc.    mię, mnie    cię, ciebie    go, jego    je
```

There are also pronoun forms beginning with *ni-*, they are used only after prepositions, e.g. `czekam na niego` “I'm waiting for him.” The complete chart of the case forms of the Polish personal pronouns can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_morphology#Pronouns).